# Adding g- to cscopequickfix breaks tag stack jumps

Tags: vim, cscope

I want `cs find g` results also to `quickfix` window. So I added `g-` to `cscopequickfix`. But when I do this, I can't jump back in tag stack because it says the tag stack is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is expected behavior. When `cs find <query>` results are sent to quickfix, they are not sent to taglist. That's why `Ctrl-T` can't be used to go back.

Best alternative is to use jumplist - `Ctrl-O` and `Ctrl-I`.